# Is it OK to connect smtp server once and send many emails in a long period?

Tags: python, email, smtp

here is the code from my college, but I thougt it's not much effecient 'cause it'll connect smtp server and login every time, and just send one mail..., so how about I connect smtp and login for the first time once the service started, and using this long connection to send mail aferwards?

```
def send_email(receiver, subject, mail_body):
    msg = MIMEText(mail_body, _subtype='html', _charset='utf-8')
    msg['Subject'] = Header(subject, 'utf-8')
    msg['From'] = XXXX@xx.com
    msg['To'] = receiver

    try:
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
        smtp.connect(xxxx.com)
        smtp.login(user, password)
        smtp.sendmail(XXXX@xx.com, receiver.split(','), msg.as_string())
    except Exception:
        logger.error('Send email failed: %s' % traceback.format_exc())
    finally:
        smtp.quit()
```

Comment: Call `smtp.sendmail(...)` as many as you want and do the `smtp.quit()` when you finish all the sending job. 
Or just don't put the `smtp.quit()` in the function, split it to another function and rewrite the program.

Comment: what if I never quit the connection for e.g. one year?

Comment: The server is free terminate the connection at any time, so it will probably not have a connection idling around for that long. If you want to reuse a connection you have to implement code that on errors decide if they are temporary (in this case implement a retry,mavbe with a wait period) or if they are permanent (e.g. wrong credentials); in this case abort and notify the user of the error code and message. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMTP_server_return_codes

Comment: Thanks, that's just what i want, maybe you could put this comments in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK to reuse the connection to send email, but the server may terminate the connection at any time, that depends on server's strategy. So just catch the corresponding error and reconnect again.

Answer (score 0):

```
def send_email(receiver, subject, mail_body):
   try:
       smtp = smtplib.SMTP()
       smtp.connect(xxxx.com)
       smtp.login(user, password)
       # for test           
       for i in range (10):
           smtp.sendmail(XXXX@xx.com, receiver.split(','), msg.as_string())

   except Exception:
    logger.error('Send email failed: %s' % traceback.format_exc())
   finally:
    smtp.quit()
```

using the above code, I test sending 10 emails using the same connection, but got Exception below, I think that may be related to the safety strategy of target smtp server.

```
[2021-03-01 15:56:25,386] [ERROR] [125:MainThread] [send_email.py:47] [send_email]:send email failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "send_email.py", line 41, in send_email
smtp.sendmail(EmailAccount, email_receiver.split(','), msg.as_string())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 737, in sendmail
raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
SMTPSenderRefused: (450, 'Requested mail action not taken: too much delivery in this connection', 'xxxx@xxxx.com')
```